# Subscripting an array with an … array?

Tags: arrays, jq

jq is straightforward for the most part, but I'm at a loss trying to decypher the following jq program. How does it work? Apparently, it finds the index of the value in the array. But how can this syntax be explained? Can it be deconstructed to be more explicit?

I'm aware of the `indices/1` function … but this function is defined as `def indices($i): .[[$i]];` (simplified) – which led me to ask this question.

```
echo '[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]' | jq '.[[1]]' # output: [0,6]; 1 occurs at index 0 and 6
echo '[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]' | jq '.[[2,3]]' # output: [1]; [2,3] occurs at index 1
echo '[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]' | jq '.[2,3]' # output: 3 4; stream of values at index 2 and 3
```

I haven't found anything in [the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ArrayIndex:.%5B2%5D) explaining this behavior. How does `.[x]` relate to `.[[x]]`, and `.[x,y]` to `.[[x,y]]`? Is this syntax (`.[[x]]`) documented somewhere?

Comment: "The input may be an array, in which case if s is an array then the indices output will be those where all elements in . match those of s."

Comment: @0stone0 I appreciate the comment, but that quote is from `indices/1`. I'm specifically asking about the syntax `.[[$x]]` (with $x being any valid number)

Comment: The downvoting behavior in the [tag:jq] tag is somewhat interesting. How can this question be improved? Which research effort would make it better? Is it unclear? Is it too simple? I want to improve it, but without comments how it is bad, I can not.

Comment: I agree about the downvoting: would be nice to see some feedback. I suspect the problem is  this question boils down to "I was looking in the source code and found this strange undocumented implementation detail. How can I find out more about it?" -- the answer seems to be "yes it's undocumented: keep reading more source code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for arrays as input, if A is an array, then `.[A]` asks for the sorted array of ALL the indices, $i, such that `.[0:$i] + A` is an initial subarray of the input.

Examples:

```
jq -nc '[0,1,2,3,4,1,2] | .[[1,2]]'
[1,5]

gojq -nc '[0,1,2,3,4,1,2] | .[[1,2]]'
[1,5]
```

As you note, `indices/1` on arrays is defined using this feature, and the jq manual mentions this feature of `indices/1`:

> The input may be an array, in which case if s is an array then the indices output will be those where all elements in . match those of s.

The [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) also has some pertinent documentation at

> : Given an array, A, containing an item, X, how can I find the least index of X in A? Why does [[1](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)] | index([1](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)) return null rather than 0? Why does [1,2] | index([1,2]) return 0 rather than null?

Unfortunately, the jq manual itself does not make the connection explicit.

`Note:` jaq has a different take on this.

---

Footnotes:

(a) The behavior of `B|.[A]` when A and B are JSON arrays is now documented on the jq wiki at [How to: Avoid Pitfalls](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls)

(b) `.[x,y]` evaluates to`.[x], .[y]` by the ordinary rules governing the comma-operator.

Comment: Thanks. I think my question might be misguided, and I should have left out the `.[[x,y]]` case. `indices/1` is defined as `.[[x]]` for non-array inputs and this is really what I want to know. Is this syntax feature documented somewhere? Or is this an "undocumented implementation details" as glenn jackman has put it in the comments?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I begin to see it! `[x,y]` and `[x]` are both arrays. With `a=[…]`, then `.[a]` will find the indices of this array, regardless of how many items the array has. Although I think the quote from `indices/1` is about the input to the `indices` function (because it is possible to call `indices(1)` as well as `indices([1])`; both calls will be converted to `.[[1]]`)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your gyrations. It might help if you adopt the rule that if some behavior of jq has been stable since version 1.4, then the corresponding definition(s) in builtin.jq can be taken as documentation, especially if gojq mimics the behavior.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have the impression we are miscommunicating. You are referencing the definitions in builtin.jq as documentation. BUT I'm not asking about the definition of `indices`, I'm asking about the definition of `.[[1]]`. The final version of this answer however answers the question by linking to the (newly added) "How to: Avoid pitfalls" section in the FAQ. Thanks a lot!